# Sorting table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

My table data like

```
id LedgerName
1  "105 AAA"
2  "102 sss"
3  "GGGG"
4  "107 BBB"
5  "BBBB"
6  "101 TTT"
```

i want sorting the Ledger like

```
6  "101 TTT"
2  "102 sss"
1  "105 AAA"
4  "107 BBB"
5  "BBBB"
3  "GGGG"
```

Normal Order by is not working. 
i used split function to split for number based sorting in order by ..
how to fix this issue

Comment: you don't have to split the data for sorting, a simple "order by LedgerName" will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the data you have provided a regular order by on LedgerName is doing what you want.
Below is version that deals with data that is a bit more complicated.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/931c3/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  id int,
  LedgerName varchar(20)
)

insert into YourTable values
(1,  '105 AAA'  ),
(2,  '1020 sss' ),
(3,  ' '        ),
(4,  null       ),
(5,  '0'        ),
(6,  '999 sss'  ),
(7,  '9999 sss' ),
(8,  'GGGG'     ),
(9,  '107 BBB'  ),
(10, 'BBBB'     ),
(11, '101 TTT'  )
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id,
       LedgerName
from YourTable
order by case when patindex('%[^0-9]%', isnull(LedgerName, '')+' ') = 1 then 1 else 0 end,
         cast(left(LedgerName, patindex('%[^0-9]%', LedgerName+' ')-1) as int),
         LedgerName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/931c3/1/0)**:

```
| ID | LEDGERNAME |
-------------------
|  5 |          0 |
| 11 |    101 TTT |
|  1 |    105 AAA |
|  9 |    107 BBB |
|  6 |    999 sss |
|  2 |   1020 sss |
|  7 |   9999 sss |
|  4 |     (null) |
|  3 |            |
| 10 |       BBBB |
|  8 |       GGGG |
```